# Need help in unlocking apt-get gparted

Tags: apt, permissions

Can someone walk me through getting gparted on my computer so that I can install a second hard drive. This is the error I get everytime I write in

```
$ apt-get install gparted.
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: On a terminal window `sudo gparted`

Comment: @bistoco No, Robert is currently trying to *install* gparted. Your command would run it, but not in a good way. Never use `sudo` to run GUI applications as root. Gparted comes with a command that automatically elevates your privileges using `pkexec`. Therefore you should run **`gparted-pkexec`** to start it instead of `sudo gparted`.

Comment: @RoberScott You want to run `sudo apt-get install gparted`, because installing packages requires root privileges and therefore you need the `sudo`. It will then also ask you to enter your account password.

Comment: @ByteCommander, can you please explain why "never"?

Comment: @bistoco Please read this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/270006/367990

Answer (score -1):

Like heemayl said, you need so run `sudo apt-get install gparted` so that you run the `apt-get` command as root (adding sudo before a command in default ubuntu tells the computer that you want to run the command as root.)

Root in Linux gives you unlimited access to your computer, meaning that you can ruin pretty much anything you want, so use it with care.

Comment: heemayl didn't say that, he put in a close vote, marking this question as a duplicate of the one he linked. Please don't answer duplicate questions with the same answer given at the original